# log4j2 starting from 1 after restarting application

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

Hi I am using log4j2 and using rollover based on time and size. I  am using file name as Application.log ,when rollover happens , previous filename appends with index but after system restarts count is again starting from 1 instead of continuing from previous count and its overwriting all existing files. is there way I can avoid it?

if last file name was Application.log.10

if I restart application, when next file roll over it should continue from 11.